# Angular - reactive form - material - color icon when invalid

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm preparing reactive form in Angular (with Material), nad I would color icon, when the field is invalid.

`component class`

```
wholeForm = new FormGroup({
...
contact: new FormGroup({
  ...
  city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
}),
...
```

});

`component html template`

```
<form [formGroup]='wholeForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
...
<div class="form-group" formGroupName="contact">

    ...
          <div class='code-city'>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input formControlName="postalCode" matInput maxlength="5" placeholder="postal code*">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input formControlName="city" matInput placeholder="city*">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

I tried to add some local reference to `city` input and in `mat-icon` `[class.red-icon]='city.invalid'`, but it didn't work. Next I also tried to bind class to propertie in class, without result.

CSS class works, when i hardcoded to `wholeForm.valid`.

`CSS`

```
.red-icon{
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code,

```
<div class='code-city'>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="postalCode" matInput maxlength="5" placeholder="postal code*">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="city" matInput placeholder="city*">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

and in **style.css**

```
.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-icon {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, It will work for all the invalid mat-form-field, If this help to you then please vote up.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
[class.red-icon]="wholeForm.controls.contact.controls['city'].invalid && wholeForm.controls.contact.controls['city'].touched"
```

Comment: Correct answer. Especially good for single and outstanding input validation. 

I mark different solution, because that is more universal.


Your answer shows method to go inside form propertie. It's nice! Can You tell me why did you use 'controls.contact' and next "controls['city']"? Is there any difference? I saw that, when i used '.' IDE show me some error (but it works), and when I use "['...']" IDE don't show anything and it still works.

Comment: as you said IDE shows error when we use '.' it's because of typescript that check the errors before run time, when we use "['...']" typescript can't detect the object and consider it as correct but when we use '.' it can find the objects hierarchy and shows error.but both is correct in run time.

Comment: So generally when should I use '.' and when "['...']"?

Comment: in my experience when we can access our object interface Type completely we can use '.' and in other way use  "['...']" , but not sure, check it with IDE :D